# finding formula for matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find formula for $ M^n $ for following $M$.
$$
M=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 1 \\
    -1 & -1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Can I get a solution for this? Solution should be in real numbers, not in the form of complex numbers. Preferably, Using Complex eigenvector and diagonalization, but any solution would do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

If $M=PDP^{-1}$ then $M^n=PD^nP^{-1}$ where $P$ is matrix with eigenvectors and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

Now you can find $M^n$ for your matrix.

Comment: I got your point, but the problem is those eigenvalues/eigenvectors are complex values. But I need to express those form without complex numbers. could you give me more clues? Thanks.

Comment: @DMK Yes, you will get answer in complex numbers only. I got the eigenvalues as $-1+i$ and $-1-i$

Comment: @DMK It is also easy to find the diagonal matrix and you will have complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks but... the form shouldn't be containing complex numbers. m powers n should be represented only using **real numbers**.  complex-diagonalization contains, i think , complex values if we powers them up. So I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the first cases:
\begin{align}
M^2&=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
     \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
    =\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\\[6px]
M^3&=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
     \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
    =\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
\\[6px]
M^4&=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
     \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
    =\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 \end{bmatrix}=-4I
\end{align}
This should give the idea: if $n=4q+r$, with $0\le r<4$, then
$$
M^n=(M^4)^qM^r=(-4)^qM^r
$$